# C# how to record a video or audio from a web camera and microphone and upload to a web server

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-applications, audio, video

I am seeking solutions to record a video or an audio from a web camera and microphone from clients' side and upload them to a web server or Youtube server.

Flash is not allowed to be used. So are there any other solutions?

I have searched the similar topics for a while but found that they are not helpful.

Is the SilverLight a possible option?
If it is, how to do that with SL?

Thanks,

Update:
Is there any solution which could be able to cross platforms, such as on the iPhone and iPAD?

Comment: Why would Silverlight be allowed if Flash is forbidden?

Comment: Do you need to be able to view the live video/audio feed? Or are you wanting to backup "chunks" of compressed video/audio?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, because Apple is not going to support Flash Player in the near future and many other mobile OS are going to do so.

Comment: @axon I only want to record a video or audio and upload it to a server. That's it.